# different margin for print Window in different system

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am working on print Form in web page, when I get print in my system everything is OK, but when I open my web page in different system and get print there is a different margin for print window I set a same value for chrome setting'margin'.

Comment: could be related to an error in your code, a difference in browser (or just browser version), a difference in print drivers, or many more things. Without more detail it's impossible for us to say. There's no magic answer. Consider whether _you_ could answer such a brief question? It's like going to a garage and saying to the mechanic "sometimes my car doesn't work properly" but not actually showing him the car or giving any specific details about the circumstances when the problem occurs. I'm not really sure what you expect us to say?

Comment: Edit your question to give enough info such that someone might stand a chance of actually being able to reproduce your error. Show us useful things like screenshots so we can visualise the difficulty...or better still make a runnable demo using StackSnippets or CodePen or something. Help us to help you. We're interested in helping you but unless you put some effort into your question it's going to be impossible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: @majid_shoorabi consider to generate PDF file and print it (you can do it in javascript with proper libraries) to have similar results on different systems